# How to follow a link with data-params using rvest

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to web scrape a public data provider but I got stuck when I had to click on a button passing a parameter to the JS. Here's my attempt:

```
require(rvest)
url <- 'https://myterna.terna.it/SunSet/Public/'
page <- url %>% read_html()
node_link <- page %>% html_node('.sub-item:nth-child(1) .postlink')
```

In `node_link` I can easily find the target page as the `href` of this HTML tag:

```
<a href="/SunSet/Public/Pubblicazioni"
   class="postlink"
   data-params="filter.IdSezione=52767620567B3077E053A8829B0A9478">
```

The point is that I cannot easily retrieve the content of the linked page because there are other buttons that point to the **same link**. The only difference between the various buttons is the `data-params` attribute which probably has to be given to the JS in order to retrieve the specific content.

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory heads-up:

It's not really clear if the site allow scraping, the `Legal Notice` says *Authorization is granted for the reproduction of documents published on this website exclusively for personal use and not for commercial purposes, provided the name of source is  properly indicated.*

Use this respecting their terms of service.

Inspecting the network activity when clicking on that link, we can see the webpage makes a `POST` request to `https://myterna.terna.it/SunSet/Public/Pubblicazioni/List`. We can find both the requested `headers` and the `params` sent.

```
par <- '{"draw":1,"columns":[{"data":0,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":1,"name":"","searchable":true,"orderable":true,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":2,"name":"","searchable":false,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":3,"name":"","searchable":false,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":4,"name":"","searchable":false,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":5,"name":"","searchable":false,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":6,"name":"","searchable":false,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}},{"data":7,"name":"","searchable":false,"orderable":false,"search":{"value":"","regex":false}}],"order":[],"start":0,"length":10,"search":{"value":"","regex":false},"filter":{"IdSezione":"52767620567B3077E053A8829B0A9478","Titolo":"","Id":"","ExtKey":"","TipoPubblicazione":"","SheetName":"","Anno":"2017","Mese":"7","Giorno":"","DataPubblicazione":"","TipoDatoPubblicazione":""},"details":{}}'
```

This is `json`, we can parse and change its values if we want (although I tried a few different filters and it does no respond much)

```
par <- jsonlite::fromJSON(par)
par$filter$Mese <- '7'
```

As for headers only `X-Requested-With:MLHttpRequest` is really needed so we can cut it down to that.

```
response <- POST('https://myterna.terna.it/SunSet/Public/Pubblicazioni/List', 
     add_headers('X-Requested-With' = 'XMLHttpRequest'),
     body = par,
     encode = 'json')

json_data <- content(response)$data
```

This returns a list, that we can safely transform to a dataframe for convenient use:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(json_data), nrow=length(json_data), byrow=TRUE))

head(df, 2)
#>                                                                     X1
#> 1       SbilanciamentoAggregatoZonale_SegnoGiornaliero_Orario_20170709
#> 2 SbilanciamentoAggregatoZonale_SegnoGiornaliero_QuartoOrario_20170709
#>                      X2
#> 1 /Date(1499680800000)/
#> 2 /Date(1499680800000)/
#>                                                                                            X3
#> 1 <div class="actions detail-inline export" data-pk="53F4A57FCB70304EE0532A889B0A7758"></div>
#> 2 <div class="actions detail-inline export" data-pk="53F4A57FCB6D304EE0532A889B0A7758"></div>
#>                                 X4 X5                              X6
#> 1 53F4A57FCB70304EE0532A889B0A7758 25        SEGNO_MACROZONALE_ORARIO
#> 2 53F4A57FCB6D304EE0532A889B0A7758 25 SEGNO_MACROZONALE_QUARTO_ORARIO
#>                  X7            X8
#> 1 Segno Giornaliero        Orario
#> 2 Segno Giornaliero Quarto Orario
```

Comment: Thank you @GGamba, you got the point! I think there is not so much on this subject around the web, so your contribution is definitely useful!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, basicly I was missing the mechanism of how HTTP works. After some days of study I understood the correct approach is using `httr` package the way showed below.

First of all I retrieved all the settings needed from the public page:

```
lnkd_url <- paste0(dirname(dirname(url)),
                   node_link %>%
                       html_attr('href'))
lnkd_id <- strsplit(zs_node %>%
                       html_attr('data-params'), '=')[[1]][2]
```

Then it is possible to launch the POST request to the target page:

```
lnkd_page <- POST(lnkd_url,
                  body = list('filter.IdSezione' = lnkd_id)
```

That's it!